# docker redis container startup issue

Tags: docker, redis, redis-sentinel

I have question about docker redis-sentinel:5.0.10 startup issue.

I am running docker on CentOS7 Linux.

Before 5.0.10 version I used 4.0.9 and image was taken from our own repository, now I switched to bitnami repo.

The main problem is that I try to use redis-sentinel:5.0.10 (or redis-sentinel:5.0.7) and it falls into restart loop and cannot start properly.

I run containers like that:

```sh
[root@XXX opt]# docker run -d -p 26380:26379 -v /opt/app/redis:/data --name redis-sentinel -e REDIS_MASTER_HOST=XXX.XXX.XXX -e REDIS_MASTER_SET=XXX-XXX -e REDIS_SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER_MILLISECONDS=30000 -e REDIS_SENTINEL_QUORUM=2 -e REDIS_SENTINEL_FAILOVER_TIMEOUT=180000 --net=host --restart=always bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0.10
[root@XXX opt]# docker run -d --net=host -v /opt/app/redis:/data -v /opt/app/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name redis-client --restart=always redis:5.0.10-alpine redis-server --slaveof XXX.XXX.XXX 6379
```

In log there are messages like:

```sh
redis-sentinel 10:16:50.45 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-sentinel container
redis-sentinel 10:16:50.45 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel
redis-sentinel 10:16:50.45 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel/issues
redis-sentinel 10:16:50.46 
redis-sentinel 10:16:50.46 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis sentinel setup **
redis-sentinel 10:16:50.47 ERROR ==> The configuration file /opt/bitnami/redis-sentinel/etc/sentinel.conf is not writable
```

Why it is not writable?

```sh
[root@dam31 ~]# docker run --rm -it bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0.10 sh
redis-sentinel 14:03:36.16 
redis-sentinel 14:03:36.16 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-sentinel container
redis-sentinel 14:03:36.17 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel
redis-sentinel 14:03:36.17 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel/issues
redis-sentinel 14:03:36.17 

$ cd /opt/bitnami/redis-sentinel/etc/
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 9797 Dec  8 13:25 sentinel.conf
```

`docker ps` command says:

```sh
[root@XXX app]# docker ps --no-trunc
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                           COMMAND                                                                                          CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
45988acb45407dfc7a19f4a2a08da7c8f7a99381a97bc17a3ae985d377605462   redis:5.0.10-alpine             "docker-entrypoint.sh redis-server --slaveof XXX.XXX.XXX 6379"                               4 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                        redis-client
94b9b8e712e2219bc3f9a18aba349985968e3410c5336905282fb43b38e89e8e   bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0.10   "/opt/bitnami/scripts/redis-sentinel/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis-sentinel/run.sh"   4 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 19 seconds ago                       redis-sentinel
```

On other machines I have upgraded redis to 5.0.7 version successfully and it runs properly, nothing was done otherwise:

```sh
[root@XXX app]# docker ps --no-trunc
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                          COMMAND                                                                                                    CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
07e535350c02a67478dd07708a06798981fe7e99ae448567837dacdee198ec1e   redis:5.0.7-alpine             "docker-entrypoint.sh redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --slaveof XXX.XXX.XXX 6379"   8 weeks ago         Up 8 weeks                              redis-client
fea1bff3b2c1fbc9c7cea2becad64b7e2727dfc1f73f1d541e08b9b75143b3a9   bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0.7   "/entrypoint.sh /run.sh"                                                                                   8 weeks ago         Up 8 weeks                              redis-sentinel
```

If I run on the same machine (where I tried to run redis:5.0.10) redis:5.0.7 the same error occured:

```sh
[root@XXX ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
15cdd46fa325        redis:5.0.7-alpine             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                                       redis-client
b0b02a36b68c        bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0.7   "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   16 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 50 seconds ago                       redis-sentinel
```

```sh
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.86 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-sentinel container
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.87 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.87 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel/issues
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.87 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.87 
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.87 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis sentinel setup **
redis-sentinel 14:16:23.88 ERROR ==> The configuration file /opt/bitnami/redis-sentinel/etc/sentinel.conf is not writable
```

What I am doing wrong? Any thoughts? (NB! SELinux is disabled)

Comment: How are you starting the container?  You can override the command a container runs when it starts up, like `docker run --rm -it bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0.10 sh` to get a debugging shell in a new container based on the same image.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I added output of that command to my post and also how I run the container.